# Trying to send a colleague a linked powerpoint and excel file

Tags: excel, powerpoint

So I have a template powerpoint filled with graphs and tables that link directly with an associated excel file. I made it on my PC and updating the excel updates the relevant fields in the ppt, etc.

My problem is twofold:

1. The excel and ppt are both templates that I update for every new batch of work with new variables. I'd like to start new batches without over-writing the templates i.e. I'd like to save as 'Project 23/12/14'. But doing so on the PPT of course keeps the link with the old spreadsheet, and doing so on the spreadsheet with a new name means it no longer links to the PPT. I could manually update all the links each time, but there are quite a few and it somewhat defeats the purpose of speeding up the process!
2. I'd like to send a colleague the ppt/excel but the ppt links to the original addresses for the excel in my computer. Again, is there a way of sending the two documents as a discrete entity?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Start reading about dynamically creating/altering documents. Such tasks can be automated. Alternatively you could include a link not to a specific document, but to a service url which is served by some script. That script could, for example, always deliver the newest version of a file. That way the url stays the same but different files get delivered upon request.

Answer (score 0):

PPT used to handle this kind of linking nicely, but that was long ago in a galaxy far away where the alternate universe of MS programmers had a clue what links are and how users might actually need them to work.  Busted now though.

It's going to look for links on an absolute path, so if you want to distribute a set of linked XL and PPT files, you'll need to put them on a path that recipients can easily duplicate and make sure that they do so.

Batch-changing links is fairly simple with a bit of VBA, though. There's an example here:

Batch Search and Replace for Hyperlinks, OLE links, movie links and sound links
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00773_Batch_Search_and_Replace_for_Hyperlinks-_OLE_links-_movie_links_and_sound_links.htm